# In tensorflow, is variable value the only context information a session stores?

Tags: tensorflow

Suppose we run `session.run([tensor_to_eval])`, is it true that the only resident information is the tf.Variable values, and all other evaluations results are either returned from the call, or discarded?

Suppose we have two sessions, do they share anything except for the default graph?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are various forms of state retained between [`run()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/client.html#Session.run) calls ("steps") in a TensorFlow [session](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/client.html#Session):

- As you already pointed out, [`tf.Variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Variable) objects store values between invocations, which may be read and written by any step.
- TensorFlow queues ([tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/how_tos/threading_and_queues/index.html)) allow you to [enqueue one](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#QueueBase.enqueue) or [many](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#QueueBase.enqueue_many) values into a bounded buffer in a step, and [dequeue one](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#QueueBase.dequeue) or [many](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#QueueBase.dequeue_many) values in a later step. Queues also support coordination between steps, such as back-pressure in a producer/consumer relationship. They also allow you to switch between element-by-element and batched computation, using functions like [`tf.train.batch()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#batch).
- TensorFlow readers ([tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/how_tos/reading_data/index.html)) act like implicit file pointers that remember their current position in a file between steps. Subsequent executions of the [`read()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#ReaderBase.read) op yield, for examples, different [lines of a text file](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#TextLineReader).

In the single-process version of TensorFlow, sessions do not share any state. They may share the same graph (if they are both created with the same default graph), but the stateful components (such as the `tf.Variable` objects) will assume different values in the different sessions.

The [distributed runtime](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/README.md) adds support for "resource containers" that are shared between sessions. These cover variables, queues, and readers, and can be configured by passing the optional `container` argument to the constructor for these objects.